# How to use the result of snprintf and send from server to client in socket programming C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, encryption, sgx

I have this function which prints the hmac of a string:

```
char *print_bits(unsigned char *bits, size_t len)
{
  int i;
  char buf[64], *put = buf;
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
  put += snprintf(put, 64, "%02x", bits[i]);
}
return put;
}
```

I want to use the result of printf and it send to my client app:

```
char buffer[64]
len = strlen(buffer);
    if(len < BUFFERSIZE)
         {
    gen_hmac_sha256(global_eid, (unsigned char *) buffer, len + 1);
    get_hmac_sha256(global_eid, hmac_sha256_out, HMAC_SHA256_LEN);
    printf("App.cpp: hmac sha256 hash: ");
    char *buffer2 = print_bits(hmac_sha256_out, 32);
    printf("\n");
    
    send(new_sock, buffer2, 64, 0);
}
```

However, send is not sending the result to the client. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `print_bits` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of reaching the closing brace of a non-void function without encountering a `return` statement.

Comment: I have tried to return a char value, but that didn't work either. Can you show me an example? Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve in `print_bits`

Comment: Use `sprintf` if you want to write characters to a string buffer.  `printf` writes to the standard output stream.  Since you've marked this as C++, you might instead consider using a `std::ostringstream` along with some I/O manipulators.

Comment: `printf` writes to the standard output stream, not your sock.  If you want to send data to your sock that has the same layout as a printf result, then you could use the `snprintf` function to createa  memory buffer with that layout and then send that to your sock

Comment: print_bits is a function call that print the digest of a string in SGX. The code is long that is why I only showed the relevant points.

Comment: Hey M.M, thanks. I am relatively new to c++. I did try snprintf but keep getting errors: connot convert char** to char*

Comment: Try looking at some sample programs for snprintf

Comment: @M.M I got it to work using snprintf. Thanks. I am unsure if I can post the answer since I asked the question. Thanks again.

Comment: @Shegs01 yes it's fine to answer your own question , it may help other people with the same question

Answer (score 0):

In your function `print_bits`, you are returning address to local variable/array. This will lead to undefined behaviour as you will be pointing to a memory region that you no longer have ownership and some other function/code can modify it.

Since, you are using `C++`, you can write the same code using `std::string`.

```
std::string get_bits_str(unsigned char *bits, size_t len)
{
  std::stringstream stream;
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
      stream << std::hex << bits[i] << " ";
  return stream.str();
}
```

```
std::string buf = print_bits(hmac_sha256_out, 32);
printf("\n");
    
send(new_sock, buf.c_str(), 64, 0);
```

Comment: thanks, but this was not printing the hmac string. However, I was able to use snprintf to send the hmac string to the client.

Comment: I got but it's safer to use `std::string`. Any reason you want to stick to `char` array?

Comment: No specific reason, the code is long and intertwined so changing that would probabaly cause problems for me. I am new to c++.

Answer (score 0):

Create a buffer to hold the hmac string gotten from the print_bits function using snprintf as shown below:

```
char buf [64];
char *print_bits(unsigned char *bits, size_t len)
{
   int i;
   
   for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
     snprintf(buf+i*2, 3, "%02x", bits[i]);
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Then in the main function, use the send() system call as shown below to send from server to the client.

```
len = strlen(buffer);
if(len < BUFFERSIZE)
 {
     gen_hmac_sha256(global_eid, (unsigned char *) buffer, len + 1);
     get_hmac_sha256(global_eid, hmac_sha256_out, HMAC_SHA256_LEN);
     printf("App.cpp: hmac sha256 hash: ");
     send(new_sock, print_bits(hmac_sha256_out, 32), 64, 0); 
 }
```

Note that the hmac algorithm itself is executed inside Intel SGX and has not been shown.